# scrapy - error that I don't understand

Tags: python, scrapy

My Spyder IDE says that `'scrapy.dupefilter' is deprecated,

> use 'scrapy.dupefilters' instead

```
return f(*args, **kwds)`
```

What can I do?

Comment: That is not error but a friendly warning. Don't worry. And please delete this question :)

Comment: I can't do anything to use `scrapy.dupefilters` instead of `scrapy.dupefilter`?

Comment: I delete the question after this, promise ;)

Comment: You *can* use it since the method exists, just don't depend on the method to be there when you upgrade scrapy library

Comment: @cricket_007 Correct. I loved the comment but I don't think  a comment can be an answer. Like it is right now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like comment above stated it's a warning. What it means that somewhere in your code you are using old import `scrapy.dupefilter` where's the new import now is `scrapy.dupefilters` (note the `s` at the end).

When dev team decides to change things in new version they still need to support the old way of doing things because otherwise the new version wouldn't be abble to support old code.
Thus deprication warnings exist: "this thing you are using works but will not work anymore in the future, use this new thing instead!"

Comment: Thank you!! How could I use this new one please?

Comment: You need to find where in your code you are using old import: `scrapy.dupefilter` and change it to new `scrapy.dupefilters`.

Comment: It works, I delete this question as ask by @Nabin in five minutes

Comment: @P.Postrique I don't think it's a bad question, you can keep it up. Deprecation warnings is a worthwhile subject and not as intuative as some might think. And scrapy has a lot of those too. If anyone feels that it's a bad question they can vote for closing of it and other people/moderators will review the complaints.

Comment: While your point may be correct, but I believe neither this problem will be replicated nor your answer has anything new. You have simply stated what does __deprecated__ means in the world of programming. Just my view though :)